# How to connect PyCharm to a Heroku postgres database

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, pycharm

Trying to connect to our Heroku database via PyCharm which understandably requires SSL.

Is there a way to do this using the built in SSL for *.herokuapp.com?

Essentially trying to work out how to get the .pem files for PyCharm (specifically CA file, Client cert file, Client key file).

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no need to configure the files. Just append the following to the automatically generated url:

```
?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

So the correct url will be:

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

It does not seem to matter if you check SSL or not.  The param ssl=true will force an ssl connection.

Comment: This requires an `&` appended to the end to work for me